# Creating an object without its known type

Tags: c++, boost, reflection, stdmap

I was wondering how can I create an object if type of this object is stored in a string. My goal is to optimise it as good as it's possible, this algorithm will be iterated many times. I know 3 possible solutions:

1. Creating a list (vector?) of possible classes and iterating over all possible variants (slow as hell if i have >10 possible classes)
2. std::map approach (creating a map and checking all of it) (performance not checked)
3. Using Boost::PFR (kind of "reflection" library for C++) (performance also not known)

Do you know which approach would be the best and fastest options? And how to implement that?
Sincerely, Karol

Comment: Think of this: why do you need to store the types? How would you handle the created objects?

Comment: you can register all your types and have factory which would create an item based on given key (string? better to have intermediate key)

Comment: General advice for any performance question is to test it to find out if it fits your needs. Much more accurate than random internet people speculating about code they can't see.

Comment: Ripi2, I need to store the types to draw all of the objects in scene. 
TheUndeadFish, I'll post the code after I'll do these examples perfectly, now I have some problems with my code.
Anyways, thanks for your answers!

Comment: You want to do it all by yourself, or framework usage is acceptable?

Comment: Nanev, I think it's better to make it all by myself, but I can also use the framework if needed.

Comment: typeid is comparable and hashable, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

It seems your case is deserialization.

Parsing and instantiating is going to be much slower than the one virtual function dispatch for a class factory. Here's a sketch, parsing:

```
Point(3, 4.5);
Circle(Point(0,0), 42e3);
Rectangle(Point(7, -0.87654), Point (77, 9e2));
```

Into the following hierarchy:

```
struct Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const {};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shape const& s) {
        s.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

struct Point : Shape {
    double x, y;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Point(" << x << "," << y << ")";
    }
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    Point  origin;
    double radius;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Circle(" << origin << "," << radius << ")";
    }
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {
    Point topleft, bottomright;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Rectangle(" << topleft << "," << bottomright << ")";
    }
};
```

The parser is using Spirit X3:

```
namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    template <typename T>
    auto as        = [](auto expr) { return rule<struct _, T>{"rule"} = expr; };

    auto point     = as<Point>(eps >> "Point" >> "(" >> double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> ')');
    auto circle    = as<Circle>(eps >> "Circle" >> "(" >> point >> ',' >> double_ >> ')');
    auto rectangle = as<Rectangle>(eps >> "Rectangle" >> "(" >> point >> ',' >> point >> ')');
    auto shape     = point | circle | rectangle;

    auto push = [](auto& ctx) {
        auto vis = [&](auto& shape) { _val(ctx).insert(std::move(shape)); };
        apply_visitor(vis, _attr(ctx));
    };
    auto shapes = rule<struct _, Shapes>{}  //
                = skip(space)[shape[push] % ';'];
} // namespace Parser
```

Let's use a [PolyCollection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/poly_collection.html) to store the polymorphic types. You could obviously use a pointer container if you preferred, but you mentioned performance is a concern.

```
int main() {
    std::string const& input = R"(Point(3, 4.5);
    Circle(Point(0,0), 42e3);
    Rectangle(Point(7, -0.87654), Point (77, 9e2)))";

    Shapes parsed;
    if (parse(begin(input), end(input), Parser::shapes, parsed)) {
        for (auto& s : parsed) {
            std::cout << "Instantiated: " << s << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Instantiated: Rectangle(Point(7,-0.87654),Point(77,900))
Instantiated: Circle(Point(0,0),42000)
Instantiated: Point(3,4.5)
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b391cebcfaf0174)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const {};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shape const& s) {
        s.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

struct Point : Shape {
    double x, y;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Point(" << x << "," << y << ")";
    }
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    Point  origin;
    double radius;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Circle(" << origin << "," << radius << ")";
    }
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {
    Point topleft, bottomright;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Rectangle(" << topleft << "," << bottomright << ")";
    }
};

#include <boost/poly_collection/base_collection.hpp>
using Shapes = boost::poly_collection::base_collection<Shape>;

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Point, x, y)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Circle, origin, radius)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Rectangle, topleft, bottomright)

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    template <typename T>
    auto as        = [](auto expr) { return rule<struct _, T>{"rule"} = expr; };

    auto point     = as<Point>(eps >> "Point" >> "(" >> double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> ')');
    auto circle    = as<Circle>(eps >> "Circle" >> "(" >> point >> ',' >> double_ >> ')');
    auto rectangle = as<Rectangle>(eps >> "Rectangle" >> "(" >> point >> ',' >> point >> ')');
    auto shape     = point | circle | rectangle;

    auto push = [](auto& ctx) {
        auto vis = [&](auto& shape) { _val(ctx).insert(std::move(shape)); };
        apply_visitor(vis, _attr(ctx));
    };
    auto shapes = rule<struct _, Shapes>{}  //
                = skip(space)[shape[push] % ';'];
} // namespace Parser

int main() {
    std::string const& input = R"(Point(3, 4.5);
    Circle(Point(0,0), 42e3);
    Rectangle(Point(7, -0.87654), Point (77, 9e2)))";

    Shapes parsed;
    if (parse(begin(input), end(input), Parser::shapes, parsed)) {
        for (auto& s : parsed) {
            std::cout << "Instantiated: " << s << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Version using ptr_vector for comparison (more heap allocations) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9550f34b38eaed8

Comment: Do you have any good articles about deserialization? I've been looking for a while, and I haven;t found anything valuable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: All the articles will be in the context of their respective libraries/frameworks (boost serialization, protobuf, Cap'n Proto, msgpack, bson, Cereal, and a few others that I wouldn't mention anymore (MFC OMG)). Hopefully you'll find them. At least you can easily get inspiration from their feature-set/interface choices. Think versioning, portability, streaming/nonstreaming, partial/integral (de)serialization, pointer tracking, etc.)

Comment: sehe, thanks for your help!